# NSTableView Drop Focus Color

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, focus, tableview

I have a table view and when I drop something on it, I get a blue focus inside it. Now, iTunes has the same behavior but in iTunes the color of the line is a lighter blue and the line is thicker. I have added a picture to explain it better. I want to achieve the same thing but I don't know why.

The Image: http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/2871/70857947.png

Comment: The image link is dead making the question less clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think will have to disable the focus ring and draw your own in `drawRect`:

From the documentation of `NSView`'s `focusRingType`:

> You can disable a view’s drawing of
>   its focus ring by overriding this
>   method to return NSFocusRingTypeNone,
>   or by invoking setFocusRingType: with
>   and argument of NSFocusRingTypeNone.
>   You should only disable the default
>   drawing of a view’s focus ring if you
>   want it to draw its own focus ring
>   (for example, setting the background
>   color of the view), or if the view
>   does not have sufficient space to
>   display a focus ring.

Comment: Thank you. I could be wrong but isn't this for the first responder focus ring? I thought I needed something else like changing something in the NSCell but I'm not sure.